# Getting segmentation fault while executing "cat" and "wc" on text file

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with kernel 3.16.0-38-generic on an experimental environment. Recently when debugging a Java program I notice the program will always exit unexpectedly when reading a text file of around 83M line by line. (No exception, the JVM just quit silently).

I tried to download the file to local environment for further examination. But both sftp and scp failed to work. scp report "Lost connection" during the process, and Filezilla reports "Received unexpected end-of-file from SFTP server".

Finally I tried to look at the file directly. However when I cat the file, it outputs a Segmentation fault after emitting part of the file, like the following

```
....
Intersection of HYDE ST and MCALLISTER ST
60 LEAVENWORTH ST, SAN FRANCISCO, CA,Segmentation fault
```

When I wc -l the file, I simply just got a "Segmentation fault".

Anyone encountered similar problem before? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: interesting that no environment can process the file completely. My first guess is null bytes, but I don't think it should cause a Seg fault. Becuase `wc` fails, then `cat` is not failing because of some interaction with your terminal (assuming you just did `cat file`). Can the producer of the file regenerate it, maybe it was a hiccup on their end? Are other users of the dataset reporting similar problems. Can they identify what "record" has generated the text above and inspect it for problems? ....

Comment: .... Else can you get direct access to the remote host, and maybe `dd` can write the file to something (like a USB drive, I can't help with exact syntax for that, I'd have to search for it too). Good luck!

Comment: Looks like the file is seriously corrupted; an alternative could be that the OS has a more general problem. If you want to dig into the details (position in file) you could try running `cat` or `wc` under `strace`. To just fix the issue you should try to delete the file, `fsck` the disk(s), then restore the file from a backup if you have one.